# Setting up Interactivity between two different classes in different packages

Tags: java, listview, interface, javafx, listener

I have something like this:

[image]

and I need to know what the best practice is for "hooking up" interactivity.

On the left we have a RoleSlot, which consists of an assigned Employee, and 1-5 ProjectRole(s). If I click on one of those project roles, then we get to view its ProjectResp(onsibilities) on the right.

The question is, how should I do this?

**This ProjectManager class and the RoleSlot class are in different packages.**

Should I:

Set up a listener to each of those little ListViews from the ProjectManager class? That would require making the RoleSlot's private ListView accessible somehow.

Or should I make the ProjectManager implement the RoleSlotInterface and define a method like handleSelectedRole()?

Or is there another, better choice?

I'd like to know the pros and cons, if possible. Cleaner code is better code.

Comment: Take a look at the related answer to another question which discusses implementing a [role based UI in JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666982/is-there-a-way-to-implement-a-property-like-rendered-on-javafx) and [associated sample code](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/7229260).  It's not exactly the same as your question, but might give you some insights into how to handle your case.

Answer (score 0):

I would expose a read-only `selectedRoleProperty()` on the `RoleSlot` class, and a `roleProperty()` on the `ProjectResp` class. I would set up a binding between them in the `ProjectManager` class.

```
class RoleSlot {
    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<ProjectRole> selectedRoleProperty();
}

class ProjectResp {
    public ObjectProperty<ProjectRole> roleProperty();
}

class ProjectManager {
    private final RoleSlot roleSlot;
    private final ProjectResp projectResp;

    public ProjectManager() {
        roleSlot = ...;
        projectResp = ...;
        projectResp.roleProperty().bind(roleSlot.selectedRoleProperty());
    }
}
```