# JavaFX - setVisible hides the element but doesn't rearrange adjacent nodes

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

In JavaFX, if I have a scene with 2 `VBox` elements and each `VBox` has multiple `Label` in it.
If I set the top `VBox` to **invisible**, why does the bottom `VBox` **not move up** the scene where the top `VBox` was ?

The `VBox` is **invisible** but I would expect the other objects to move into its place.

I am using FXML to load my controls.

Comment: Because the first `VBox` is just invisible and not `removed` from its parent.

Comment: whether or not hidden nodes take up any space typically is the decision of the layout

Answer (score 202):

`Node.setVisible(boolean)` just toggles the visibility state of a `Node`.

To exclude a `Node` from its parents layout calculations you additionally have to set its managed state, by calling [`Node.setManaged(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setManaged-boolean-).

If you want the managed state to be updated automatically alongside the visibility, you can use a binding as @jewelsea pointed out: `node.managedProperty().bind(node.visibleProperty());`

Comment: A [binding also works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666982/is-there-a-way-to-implement-a-property-like-rendered-on-javafx), e.g., `node.managedProperty().bind(node.visibleProperty());`

Answer (score 7):

Since it's invisible, it wont move to the top. You have to remove it with something like:

```
// remove
vbox.getChildren().remove(...)
```

Once you've removed the element you want invisible then, the other element should move to the top.

Comment: AFAIK, manipulating the scene graph is more expensive than setting visible to false.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use setVisible and managedProperty together. Here is an example:

```java
myHBox.setVisible(false);
myHBox.managedProperty().bind(myHBox.visibleProperty());
```

Comment: nothing new compared to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28559958/203657) with the most upvotes, is there :)

Comment: more clearer now!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hiding the vbox you should **remove** it from the Children and if you want to show it again **add** the vbox again.

Answer (score -1):

If l want to hide and unhide a node,
I resize the node to 0 if l want to hide it. That way, the node will not occupy space since is not visible to the user, so when l want it to be visible, l adjust the size again for it to be visible.