# Hiding a table in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

I have a table declared like this in JavaFX:

@FXML private TableView tableEF;

How can I, for example when I press a button or change a value in a ComboBox, hide it completely from the GUI, and after I press another one or change again the value in the ComboBox, make it visible again?

Edit:

```
public class AllController {

private RaportPDF wrpdf;
@FXML private Pagination pagination1;
@FXML private Pagination pagination2;
@FXML private Pagination pagination3;

public void updateSarcina(Observable<Sarcina> observable) 
{
    SarcinaService service = (SarcinaService)observable;
    smodel.setAll(service.getAllSarcinas());
}
public void updatePost(Observable<Post> observable) 
{
    PostService service = (PostService)observable;
    pmodel.setAll(service.getAllPosts());
}
public void updateFisa(Observable<Elementfisa> observable) 
{
    FisaService service = (FisaService)observable;
    fmodel.setAll(service.getAllFisa());
}

public Observer<Sarcina> getSarcinaObserver() 
{
    return new Observer<Sarcina>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void update(Observable<Sarcina> observable) 
        {
            updateSarcina(observable);
        }
    };
}
public Observer<Post> getPostObserver() 
{
    return new Observer<Post>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void update(Observable<Post> observable) 
        {
            updatePost(observable);
        }
    };
}
public Observer<Elementfisa> getFisaObserver() 
{
    return new Observer<Elementfisa>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void update(Observable<Elementfisa> observable) 
        {
            updateFisa(observable);
        }
    };
}


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@FXML private TableView allTable;

@FXML private TableView<Post> tableP;
@FXML private TableView<Sarcina> tableS;
@FXML private TableView<Elementfisa> tableEF;

@FXML private TableColumn<Sarcina, String> sFirstColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<Sarcina, String> sSecondColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<Post, String> pFirstColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<Post, String> pSecondColumn;
@FXML private TableColumn<Elementfisa, String> fFirstColumn;
@FXML  private TableColumn<Elementfisa, String> fSecondColumn;

@FXML private ComboBox<String> ComboObject;

@FXML private Label firstLabel;
@FXML private Label secondLabel;
@FXML private Label thirdLabel;

@FXML private TextField firstTextField;
@FXML private TextField secondTextField;
@FXML private TextField thirdTextField;
@FXML private TextField filterTextField;

@FXML private RadioButton radioButtonFirst;
@FXML private RadioButton radioButtonSecond;
@FXML private Button addButton;
@FXML private Button updateButton;
@FXML private Button deleteButton;
@FXML private Button clearFieldsButton;
@FXML private Button raportButton;
@FXML private Pagination pagination ;
SarcinaService sservice;
PostService pservice;
FisaService fservice;

ObservableList<Sarcina> smodel;
ObservableList<Post> pmodel;
ObservableList<Elementfisa> fmodel;

private String currentComboBoxString;

private Boolean isSelectedFC;
private Boolean isSelectedSC;

ToggleGroup toggleRadioGroup = new ToggleGroup();

public AllController() 
{

}
private int intValidate(String e) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < e.length(); i++) 
    {
        if(i == 0 && e.charAt(i) == '-') 
        {
            if(e.length() == 1) 
            {
                showErrorMessage("Numar invalid !");
                return -1;
            }
            else continue;
        }
        if(Character.digit(e.charAt(i), 10) < 0) 
        {
            showErrorMessage("Numar invalid !");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(e);
}
private void fillItemsOnTable(boolean justColumns) 
{

    ObservableList<Sarcina> localModel1 = null;
    ObservableList<Post> localModel2 = null;
    ObservableList<Elementfisa> localModel3 = null;

    if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Sarcina")) 
    {
        tableP.setVisible(false);
        tableEF.setVisible(false);
        tableS.setVisible(true);
        tableS.getColumns().clear();
        tableS.getColumns().add(sFirstColumn);
        tableS.getColumns().add(sSecondColumn);
        localModel1 = this.smodel;
    }
    else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Post")) 
    {
        tableP.setVisible(true);
        tableEF.setVisible(false);
        tableS.setVisible(false);
        tableP.getColumns().clear();
        tableP.getColumns().add(pFirstColumn);
        tableP.getColumns().add(pSecondColumn);
        localModel2 = this.pmodel;
    }
    else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Fisa")) 
    {
        tableP.setVisible(false);
        tableEF.setVisible(true);
        tableS.setVisible(false);
        tableEF.getColumns().clear();
        tableEF.getColumns().add(fFirstColumn);
        tableEF.getColumns().add(fSecondColumn);
        localModel3 = this.fmodel;
    }
    if (!justColumns)
    {
        if (localModel1!=null)
        {
            tableS.setItems(localModel1);
            tableP.setVisible(false);
            tableEF.setVisible(false);
            tableS.setVisible(true);
        }
        else
            if (localModel2!=null)
            {
                tableP.setItems(localModel2);
                tableP.setVisible(true);
                tableEF.setVisible(false);
                tableS.setVisible(false);
            }
            else
            {
                tableEF.setItems(localModel3);
                tableP.setVisible(false);
                tableEF.setVisible(true);
                tableS.setVisible(false);
            }
    }
}

@FXML public void handleRaport()
{
    if (isSelectedFC) 
    {
        ObservableList<Sarcina> model = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fservice.filterRapoarte());
        ComboObject.setValue("Sarcina");
        this.fillItemsOnTable(true);
        tableS.setItems(model);
        wrpdf.addPdf(model);
    }

}

public void setService(SarcinaService sservice, PostService pservice, FisaService fservice) 
{
    this.sservice = sservice;
    this.pservice = pservice;
    this.fservice = fservice;

    this.smodel = FXCollections.observableArrayList(sservice.getAllSarcinas());
    this.pmodel = FXCollections.observableArrayList(pservice.getAllPosts());
    this.fmodel = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fservice.getAllFisa());

    this.fillItemsOnTable(false);
}
@FXML private void onActionComboBox(ActionEvent event) 
{
    String current = ComboObject.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (current.compareTo(currentComboBoxString) != 0) 
    {
        currentComboBoxString = current;
        if (current.equals("Sarcina")) 
        {
            secondLabel.setText("Desc: ");
            radioButtonSecond.setText("By Desc");
            thirdLabel.setVisible(false);
            radioButtonFirst.setVisible(false);
            thirdTextField.setVisible(false);
        }
        else if (current.equals("Post")) 
        {
            secondLabel.setText("Name: ");
            thirdLabel.setText("Type: ");
            radioButtonFirst.setText("By Name");
            radioButtonSecond.setText("By Type");
            thirdLabel.setVisible(true);
            radioButtonFirst.setVisible(true);
            thirdTextField.setVisible(true);
        }
        else if (current.equals("Fisa")) 
        {
            secondLabel.setText("Sarcina ID: ");
            thirdLabel.setText("Post ID: ");
            radioButtonFirst.setText("By Sarcina");
            radioButtonSecond.setText("By Post");
            thirdLabel.setVisible(true);
            radioButtonFirst.setVisible(true);
            thirdTextField.setVisible(true);
        }
        this.fillItemsOnTable(false);
    }
}

@FXML private void initialize() 
{

    pagination1.setPageFactory(this::createPageP);
    pagination2.setPageFactory(this::createPageS);
    pagination3.setPageFactory(this::createPageEF);

    ComboObject.getItems().addAll
    (
            "Sarcina",
            "Post",
            "Fisa"
    );
    currentComboBoxString = "Sarcina";
    ComboObject.setValue("Sarcina");

    thirdLabel.setVisible(false);
    radioButtonFirst.setVisible(false);
    thirdTextField.setVisible(false);

    isSelectedFC = true;
    isSelectedSC = false;
    radioButtonFirst.setToggleGroup(toggleRadioGroup);
    radioButtonSecond.setToggleGroup(toggleRadioGroup);
    radioButtonFirst.setSelected(true);

    if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Post")) 
    {
        tableP.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
            if (newSelection != null) 
            {
                if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Post")) 
                {
                    firstTextField.setText(((Post) newSelection).getId().toString());
                    secondTextField.setText(((Post) newSelection).getNume());
                    thirdTextField.setText(((Post) newSelection).getTip());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Sarcina")) 
    {
        tableS.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
            if (newSelection != null) 
            {

                if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Sarcina")) 
                {
                    firstTextField.setText(((Sarcina) newSelection).getId().toString());
                    secondTextField.setText(((Sarcina) newSelection).getDesc());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Fisa")) 
    {
        tableEF.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
            if (newSelection != null) 
            {
                if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Fisa")) 
                {
                    firstTextField.setText(((Elementfisa) newSelection).getId().toString());
                    secondTextField.setText(((Elementfisa) newSelection).getSarcina().getId().toString());
                    thirdTextField.setText(((Elementfisa) newSelection).getPost().getId().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}



public int itemsPerPage() 
{
    return 1;
}

public int rowsPerPage() 
{
    return 7;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public VBox createPageS(int pageIndex) 
{
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int displace = smodel.size() % rowsPerPage();
    if (displace > 0) {
        lastIndex = smodel.size() / rowsPerPage();
    } else {
        lastIndex = smodel.size() / rowsPerPage() - 1;

    }

    VBox box = new VBox(7);
    int page = pageIndex * itemsPerPage();

    for (int i = page; i < page + itemsPerPage(); i++) {
        TableView<Sarcina> tableS = new TableView<Sarcina>();
        sFirstColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Sarcina, String>("Id"));

        sFirstColumn.setMinWidth(20);

        sSecondColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Sarcina, String>("desc"));

        sSecondColumn.setMinWidth(160);

        tableS.getColumns().addAll(sFirstColumn, sSecondColumn);
        if (lastIndex == pageIndex) {
            tableS.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(smodel.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + displace)));
        } else {
            tableS.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(smodel.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + rowsPerPage())));
        }


        box.getChildren().add(tableS);
    }


    pagination2.setPageCount(smodel.size()/7+1);


    return box;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public VBox createPageP(int pageIndex) 
 {

     int lastIndex = 0;
     int displace = pmodel.size() % rowsPerPage();
     if (displace > 0) {
         lastIndex = pmodel.size() / rowsPerPage();
     } else {
         lastIndex = pmodel.size() / rowsPerPage() - 1;

     }

     VBox box = new VBox(7);
     int page = pageIndex * itemsPerPage();

     for (int i = page; i < page + itemsPerPage(); i++) {
         TableView<Post> tableP = new TableView<Post>();
         pFirstColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                 new PropertyValueFactory<Post, String>("nume"));

         pFirstColumn.setMinWidth(20);

         pSecondColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                 new PropertyValueFactory<Post, String>("tip"));

         pSecondColumn.setMinWidth(160);

         tableP.getColumns().addAll(pFirstColumn, pSecondColumn);
         if (lastIndex == pageIndex) 
         {
            tableP.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(pmodel.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + displace)));
         } else {
            tableP.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(pmodel.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + rowsPerPage())));
         }

        pagination1.setPageCount(pmodel.size()/7+1);
         box.getChildren().add(tableP);
     }
     return box;
 }


public VBox createPageEF(int pageIndex) 
{
    int lastIndex = 0;
    int displace = fmodel.size() % rowsPerPage();
    if (displace > 0) {
        lastIndex = fmodel.size() / rowsPerPage();
    } else {
        lastIndex = fmodel.size() / rowsPerPage() - 1;

    }

    VBox box = new VBox(7);
    int page = pageIndex * itemsPerPage();

    for (int i = page; i < page + itemsPerPage(); i++) 
    {


        fFirstColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Elementfisa, String>, ObservableValue<String>>()
        {
             public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Elementfisa, String> p) 
             {
                 if (p.getValue() != null && p.getValue().getSarcina() != null) 
                 {
                      return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getSarcina().getDesc());
                 } else 
                 {
                     return new SimpleStringProperty("Empty");
                 }
             }
          });
        fSecondColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Elementfisa, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() 
        {
             public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Elementfisa, String> p) 
             {
                 if (p.getValue() != null && p.getValue().getPost() != null) 
                 {
                      return new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getPost().getNume());
                 } else 
                 {
                     return new SimpleStringProperty("Empty");
                 }
             }
          });

        fFirstColumn.setMinWidth(20);
        fSecondColumn.setMinWidth(160);


        if (lastIndex == pageIndex) {
            tableEF.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(fmodel.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + displace)));
        } else if (lastIndex == pageIndex && lastIndex!=0 && pageIndex!=0) {
            tableEF.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(fmodel.subList(pageIndex * rowsPerPage(), pageIndex * rowsPerPage() + rowsPerPage())));
        }
        pagination3.setPageCount(fmodel.size()/7+1);
        box.getChildren().add(tableEF);
    }
    return box;
}





private void clearFields() 
{
    firstTextField.setText("");
    secondTextField.setText("");
    thirdTextField.setText("");
}


@FXML public void handleAdd() 
{
    String id = firstTextField.getText();
    String first = secondTextField.getText();
    String sec = thirdTextField.getText();
    int vid = intValidate(id);
    if (vid == -1)
        return;
    if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Sarcina")) 
    {
        Sarcina s = new Sarcina(Integer.parseInt(id), first);
        try {
            if (sservice.findOne(s.getId()) == null) 
            {
                sservice.save(s);
                showMessage(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Salvare cu succes", "Sarcina a fost adaugat!");
                clearFields();
            }
            else
                showErrorMessage("Exista deja o sarcina cu acest id !");
        }catch(ValidatorException e) 
        {
            showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Post")) 
    {
        Post p = new Post(Integer.parseInt(id), first, sec);
        try {
            if (pservice.findOne(p.getId()) == null) 
            {
                pservice.save(p);
                showMessage(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Salvare cu succes", "Post-ul a fost adaugat!");
                clearFields();
            }
            else
                showErrorMessage("Exista deja un post cu acest id !");
        }catch(ValidatorException e) 
        {
            showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Fisa")) 
    {
        try {
            Sarcina s = sservice.findOne(Integer.parseInt(first));
            Post p = pservice.findOne(Integer.parseInt(sec));
            if (s == null || p == null) 
            {
                showErrorMessage("Id-ul sarcinii sau postului nu exista !");
                return;
            }
            Elementfisa f = new Elementfisa(Integer.parseInt(id), p, s);
            if (fservice.findOne(f.getId()) == null) 
            {
                fservice.save(f);
                showMessage(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Salvare cu succes", "Fisa a fost adaugat!");
                clearFields();
            }
            else
                showErrorMessage("Exista deja o fisa cu acest id !");
        } catch (ValidatorException e) 
        {
            showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@FXML public void handleUpdate() 
{
    String id = firstTextField.getText();
    String first = secondTextField.getText();
    String sec = thirdTextField.getText();
    int vid = intValidate(id);
    if (vid == -1)
        return;
    if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Sarcina")) 
    {
        Sarcina s = new Sarcina(Integer.parseInt(id), first);
        try {
            Sarcina updated = sservice.update(s);
            if (updated != null) 
            {
                showMessage(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Actualizare cu succes", "Sarcina a fost actualizata!");
                clearFields();
            }
            else
                showErrorMessage("Eroare la actualizare !");
        } catch (ValidatorException e) 
        {
            showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Post")) 
    {
        Post p = new Post(Integer.parseInt(id), first, sec);
        try {
            Post updated = pservice.update(p);
            if (updated != null) 
            {
                showMessage(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Actualizare cu succes", "Postul a fost actualizat!");
                clearFields();
            }
            else
                showErrorMessage("Eroare la actualizare !");
        } catch (ValidatorException e) 
        {
            showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Fisa")) 
    {
        try {
            Sarcina s = sservice.findOne(Integer.parseInt(first));
            Post p = pservice.findOne(Integer.parseInt(sec));
            if (s == null || p == null) 
            {
                showErrorMessage("Id-ul sarcinii sau postului nu exista !");
                return;
            }
            Elementfisa f = new Elementfisa(Integer.parseInt(id), p, s);
            Elementfisa updated = fservice.update(f);
            if (updated != null) 
            {
                showMessage(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Actualizare cu succes", "Fisa a fost actualizata!");
                clearFields();
            }
            else
                showErrorMessage("Eroare la actualizare !");
        }catch (ValidatorException e) 
        {
            showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
@FXML public void handleDelete() 
{
    if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Sarcina")) 
    {
        Sarcina s = (Sarcina) tableS.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        try 
        {
            sservice.delete(s);
            showMessage(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Stergere cu succes", "Sarcina a fost stersa !");
            clearFields();
        } catch (ValidatorException e) {
            showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Post")) 
    {
        Post p = (Post) tableP.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        try 
        {
            pservice.delete(p);
            showMessage(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Stergere cu succes", "Postul a fost sters !");
            clearFields();
        } catch (ValidatorException e) 
        {
            showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Fisa")) 
    {
        Elementfisa f = (Elementfisa) tableEF.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        try 
        {
            fservice.delete(f);
            showMessage(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Stergere cu succes", "Fisa a fost stersa !");
            clearFields();
        } catch (ValidatorException e) 
        {
            showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
@FXML public void handleClearFields() 
{
    clearFields();
}
@FXML public void handleToggleButton() 
{
    isSelectedFC = radioButtonFirst.isSelected();
    isSelectedSC = radioButtonSecond.isSelected();      
}
@FXML public void handleFilterColumn() 
{
    String what = filterTextField.getText();
    try 
    {
        if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Sarcina")) 
        {
            if (what.equals("")) 
            {
                tableS.setItems(smodel);
                return;
            }
            if (isSelectedFC) 
            {
                showErrorMessage("N/A for Sarcina !");
                return;
            }
            else if (isSelectedSC) 
            {
                ObservableList<Sarcina> model = FXCollections.observableArrayList(sservice.filterSarcinaDesc(what));
                tableS.setItems(model);
            }
        }
        else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Post")) 
        {
            if (what.equals("")) 
            {
                tableP.setItems(pmodel);
                return;
            }
            if (isSelectedFC) 
            {
                ObservableList<Post> model = FXCollections.observableArrayList(pservice.filterPostNume(what));
                tableP.setItems(model);
            }
            else if (isSelectedSC) 
            {
                ObservableList<Post> model = FXCollections.observableArrayList(pservice.filterPostTip(what));
                tableP.setItems(model);
            }
        }
        else if (currentComboBoxString.equals("Fisa")) 
        {
            if (what.equals("")) 
            {
                ComboObject.setValue("Fisa");
                tableS.setItems(smodel);
                return;
            }
            int vid = intValidate(what);
            if (vid == -1)
                return;
            if (isSelectedFC) 
            {
                Sarcina s = sservice.findOne(Integer.parseInt(what));
                ObservableList<Sarcina> model = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fservice.filterElementSarcina(s));
                ComboObject.setValue("Sarcina");
                this.fillItemsOnTable(true);
                tableS.setItems(model);
            }
            else if (isSelectedSC) 
            {
                Post p = pservice.findOne(Integer.parseInt(what));
                ObservableList<Post> model = FXCollections.observableArrayList(fservice.filterElementPost(p));
                ComboObject.setValue("Fisa");
                this.fillItemsOnTable(true);
                tableP.setItems(model);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(ValidatorException e) 
    {
        showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
}
static void showMessage(Alert.AlertType type, String header, String text)
{
    Alert message=new Alert(type);
    message.setHeaderText(header);
    message.setContentText(text);
    message.showAndWait();
}

static void showErrorMessage(String text)
{
    Alert message=new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
    message.setTitle("Mesaj eroare");
    message.setContentText(text);
    message.showAndWait();
}

}
```

Edit2: The question "JavaFX - setVisible doesnt “hide” the element" isn't a solution because for him the setInvisible works, since it makes the vBox invisible, just doesn't move another one in it's place. Also I already tried the solution proposed there, nothing worked.

Also I noticed that the table *Fisa* (tableEF), hides itself when I change the value in the ComboBox.

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX - setVisible doesnt "hide" the element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558165/javafx-setvisible-doesnt-hide-the-element)

Comment: Do you want to just hide it and let it take the available space or hide it and also remove the space that it is currently occupying?

Comment: I want to change between tables on the same position. So while I hide the one table, another one should appear in it's place.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final BooleanProperty tableHidden;

public AllController()
{
    this.tableHidden = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    this.tableEF.visibleProperty().bind(this.tableHiddenProperty());
    this.tableEF.managedProperty().bind(this.tableHiddenProperty().not());

    // ...
}

// Standard FX property setter/getter...

public void makeTableHidden()
{
    this.setTableHidden(true);
    // ...
}
```

Of course, you can choose not to have a property and directly set `visibleProperty` and `managedProperty` of the `TableView`, but I thought it is neater (personal opinion) to do it this way.

### Edit

These are standard naming conventions for getters/setters of [JavaFX properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) (see Example 1).

The table's visibility is also one example of such property; its `private` property (which you cannot see) is called `visible`, its `public` version (which you can see) is `visibleProperty`, and its getter/setter are `isVisible` and `setVisible` respectively.

This is the extra piece of codes that you need to have (which I had assumed you had known how to generate one on your own).

```
public final BooleanProperty tableHiddenProperty()
{
    return this.tableHidden;
}
public final boolean isTableHidden()
{
    return this.tableHiddenProperty().get;
}
public final void setTableHidden(final boolean value)
{
    this.tableHiddenProperty().set(value);
}
```

Comment: Is tableHiddenProperty() a separate void function or I must import it from somewhere?

Comment: @Artyomska Updated.