# Change brightness of whole scene

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to change the brightness of the whole scene in javafx. This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
  StackPane root = new StackPane();

  Rectangle rec1 = new Rectangle();
  rec1.setWidth(300);
  rec1.setHeight(300);
  rec1.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED);

  ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
  colorAdjust.setBrightness(-0.8);

  root.setEffect(colorAdjust);

  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1920, 1080);
  root.getChildren().add(rec1);

  primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
  primaryStage.setScene(scene);
  primaryStage.show();
}
```

The problem is, like this only the brightness of the rectangle changes, but not the brightness of the whole scene. I also need to change the brightness of the "background". Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely this seems to be fixed by adding a node to the `StackPane` in order for it to adjust the color to everything, not just shapes. When shapes are the only thing visible, that is all that's `ColorAdjust`ed. At least one `Node` must be present. Changing the one line to the following will do what you want:

```
root.getChildren().addAll(rec1, new Label());
```

However, this could have consequences to your project by shift something slightly even though it's empty. We can get around this by making it [invisible and not-managed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28559958/2650847) so that it isn't considered in layout calculations.

```
Label fix = new Label("Fix colorAdjust whole scene.");
fix.setVisible(false);
fix.setManaged(false);

Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
root.getChildren().addAll(rec1, fix);
```