JavaFX Scene Builder: Switching forms by using managed="false" and visible="false"
I am trying to find in JavaFX Scene Builder 23.0.1 the property "managed" but cannot find it. Has anybody else an idea? Below is an example code:
Package name: package com.example.demo;
HelloApplication.java
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
    stage.setTitle("Hello!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

}
HelloController.java
    public class HelloController {
    public VBox firstVBox;
    public Button startChat;
    public VBox secondBox;
    public TextArea chatArea;

    public void switchForm(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        this.firstVBox.setManaged(false);
        this.startChat.setVisible(false);
        this.secondBox.setManaged(true);
        this.chatArea.setVisible(true);
    }
}

hello-view.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<StackPane
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
    <VBox fx:id="firstVBox" alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0">
        <Button fx:id="startChat" text="Start chat!" onAction="#switchForm"/>
    </VBox>
    <VBox fx:id="secondBox" alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" managed="false">
        <TextArea fx:id="chatArea" text="How are you doing?" visible="false"/>
    </VBox>
</StackPane>


Are you getting an error?

No I just want o figure out how to access the property "managed" in Scenebuilder. It would be a nice to know feature..

Oh, I am not sure, but what happens if you try switching out the old view with the new view instead of using managed and visible? Add the form you are switching to to the node and remove the form you are switching from.

But then I need more than one FXML file, right?

What's wrong with having more than one FXML file? In general, modularity makes programming more maintainable. This is no exception.

It's also not really clear why you'd need or want to toggle the managed property in this case.

I want to make a VBox invisible, I got the info from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28558165/javafx-setvisible-hides-the-element-but-doesnt-rearrange-adjacent-nodes

@James_D Yeah, it is better to split files to avoid one huge file. What is the minimum and  maximum lines of code for an FXML file?

But the VBoxs whose managed property you're toggling are contained in a StackPane, not in another VBox as in the linked question. Leaving them always managed will mean the StackPane will remain the same size no matter which VBox is visible, which probably feels more natural (you probably don't want the whole layout moving around when you switch what is visible). What are you trying to achieve here?

"What is the minimum and maximum lines of code for an FXML file?" It's not clear what you mean. There is no minimum and maximum.

To answer the question, it doesn't appear that managed is a property which is supported by SceneBuilder. There are a lot of properties defined just in Node and more defined for each subclass; it would be somewhat unwieldy to try to support all of them.

@James_D I added a response. Thanks for your support!

@SedJ601 I added a response. Thanks for your support!

See Loading new fxml in the same scene and the related example code, also a similar example.  There is likely more than one solution to the problem you are trying to solve and your managed/visible option is probably suboptimal.  Perhaps the links provided will give you some ideas on an approach.

@jewelsea I already changed my approach. Please see response below

By reading your comments, I decided to split the FXML file "hello-view.fxml" into smaller files (secondBox.fxml). This solution is clean and follows good separation-of-concerns principles. The UI is more modular and maintainable. I use StackPane as the root layout and BorderPane as the main content layout. Both together work well for centering and flexible replacements.
hello-view.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<StackPane
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
    <BorderPane fx:id="borderPane">
        <center>
            <VBox fx:id="firstVBox" alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0">
                <Button fx:id="startChat" text="Start chat!" onAction="#switchForm" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
            </VBox>
        </center>
    </BorderPane>
</StackPane>

secondBox.fxml
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<VBox
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.demo.SecondBox" fx:id="secondBox" alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0">
    <TextArea fx:id="chatArea" text="How are you doing?" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
</VBox>

The class HelloController.java looks now as follows:
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloController {
    public VBox firstVBox;
    public Button startChat;
    public BorderPane borderPane;

    public void switchForm() throws IOException {
        borderPane.setCenter(new FXMLLoader(HelloController.class.getResource("secondBox.fxml")).load());
    }
}

