# how to actually hide Tab from TabPane with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

previously I was working on Java Swing and now I'm trying to work with JavaFX. My Java Swing code last time:

```
//These line of code is to call method that declared in ContentPage.java
contentPage.adminFeatureEnabled(adminEnabled);
contentPage.managerFeatureEnabled(managerEnabled);
```

and in my ContentPage.java

```
//By default, all feature (or tab) are enabled.
//This method is to remove register account if the user login into the system is manager and staff
public void adminFeatureEnabled(boolean a) {
    if (!a) {
        tabPane.removeTabAt(tabPane.indexOfComponent(registerAccount));
    }
}
//This method is to remove register account and purchase order if the user who log into the system is staff
public void managerFeatureEnabled(boolean a) {
    if(!a) {
        tabPane.removeTabAt(tabPane.indexOfComponent(purchaseOrder));
    }
}
```

and in my code:

```
if (role.equals("admin")){
     contentPage.contentFrame.setTitle("Menu - Admin!");
     contentPage.disUser.setEditable(true);
     contentPage.chgRoles.setEnabled(true);
} else if(role.equals("manager")){
     contentPage.contentFrame.setTitle("Menu - Manager!");
     contentPage.chgRoles.setSelectedItem("manager");
     adminEnabled = false;
}else if (role.equals("staff")){
     contentPage.contentFrame.setTitle("Menu - Staff!");
     contentPage.chgRoles.setSelectedItem("staff");
     adminEnabled = false;
     managerEnabled = false;
}
```

The code above will perform like this:

1. when the user login with admin account, all the feature (Tab) enabled
2. when the user login as manager, some feature (tab) will be hide

My current problem now:
I wanted the same feature as above in JavaFX but I don't know how as none of the method works as I wanted.

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Related (though not tab specific): [Is there a way to implement a property like “rendered” on JAVAFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666982/is-there-a-way-to-implement-a-property-like-rendered-on-javafx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply modify the `tabs` list:

The following example adds/removes `Tab`s, when the `CheckBox`es are (un)selected.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1", new Label("1"));
    Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2", new Label("2"));

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.setPrefSize(400, 400);

    CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox("1");
    CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox("2");
    cb1.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(0, tab1);
        } else {
            tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab1);
        }
    });
    cb2.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(tab2);
        } else {
            tabPane.getTabs().remove(tab2);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(new HBox(cb1, cb2), tabPane));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because if there are many tabs and they are added and removed then it is very difficult to control tab index in tabpane. Is there another solution?

Comment: @Pavel_K No, to completely hide the `Tab`s there is no other solution than modifying the list. However usually there should be no need to access the tabs via index. If you do need to access the `Tab`s e.g. by "admin index", you could still store all `Tab`s in a different `List`...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I mean that `setVisible(false) = remove(tab)`, `setVisible(true) = add(tab)`. But `add(tab)` adds to the end of the list. If, for example I have 12 tabs and want to hide 3'th and after its hiding 2nd and 4'th were closed then when I add it to its 3'th position it will have wrong order position.

Answer (score 0):

It's been so long since the question asked, but this maybe helpful for someone.

You can try something like this.

you have a `tabPane` with three tabs `tabOne`, `tabTwo` and `tabThree`.

position index of tabs

```
tabOne - 0
tabTwo - 1
tabThree - 2
```

to hide `tabTwo`, you can use remove function and again reappear you can use set function.

to remove tab

```
tabPane.getTabs().remove(tabTwo);
```

set again with the relevant index to display at the correct location.

```
tabPane.getTabs().set(1, tabTwo);
```