# Proper way to organise model methods calling in controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, authentication, javafx-8

I implement javafx application with login page and several pages available for different user's roles.

User recognizing is implemented in Login.java class, which is supposed to be called model.
But user's string login and password appear from page elements in LoginController.java file. So now I have form submitting event handler in controller:

```
public class LoginController {
    @FXML private TextField loginField;
    @FXML private TextField passwordField;
    @FXML private Button loginButton;
    @FXML private Text messageText;

    @FXML
    protected void submitLoginForm(ActionEvent event) {
        if (!Login.getInstance().authorise(loginField.getText(), passwordField.getText())) {
            messageText.setText("Invalid credentials.");
        }
    }
```

And this is what I have in Login:

```
public class Login {
    private Scene scene;
    private User loggedUser;
    private static Login instance;

    public Login(Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
        instance = this;
    }

    public static Login getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean authorise(String userId, String password) {
        loggedUser = User.recognize(userId, password);
        if (loggedUser.equals(User.UNAUTHORISED)) {
            return false;
        }
        goToInfoScreen();
        return true;
    }
```

And User.recognize() just returns specific user, which is kept in Login class above:

```
public static User recognize(String l, String p) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(user ->
                        user.login.equals(cryptWithMD5(l.toLowerCase().trim()))
                        &&
                        user.pass.equals(cryptWithMD5(p)))
                .findFirst().orElse(UNAUTHORISED);
    }
```

This works, but I'm forced to have a static instance of each model to be called from controllers. What is more, i have getInstance() method as well as public constructor. This is weird to me.

The same situation is with logout method. I have this logic in Login model class:

```
public void logout(){
    loggedUser = null;
    goToLoginScreen();
}
```

And call it from controller using static instance:

```
@FXML protected void processLogout(ActionEvent event) {
        Login.getInstance().logout();
    }
```

In start() method I create a model Login instance:

```
 @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(),  800, 600);
        Login loginManager = new Login(scene);
        loginManager.goToLoginScreen();
```

**My question is:** 
Is this really seem to be okay to call model instance from controller? Or what is the best practice to solve such a situation? (Maybe to send model instance as controller's constructor argument? And then call only controller's methods in start() method? )

One more point: in my Login model I recognize a user role and need to hide or show some elements on next screen depending on his role.

So I probably need to get required screen's controller in my model and send user to it using some setter like this?

```
       InfoPageController controller = loader.getController();
       controller.setLoggedUser(loggedUser);
```

And then in InfoPageController say something like

```
if (loggedUser.equals(User.ADMIN)) advancedTabPane.setVisible(true);
```

Again: is this okay or there is another, proper way to adjust interface to logged user?

Comment: This question seems too broad, but, imho: 1. It's fine for controllers to "talk to" models (in fact, that's their primary purpose). 2. The model should know nothing at all about the controller or the view. Use a subscription-notification protocol so that the views/controllers know about changes in the model's data. The model should not be calling methods like `goToInfoScreen()`, which is concerned with the view. 3. Don't use static data; instead, use dependency injection to allow the controllers and views to have access to ta shared model instance. Use a DI framework if you need to simplify it

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but I created a [simple system for role based visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666982/is-there-a-way-to-implement-a-property-like-rendered-on-javafx), in case that might help.  Also (among other systems), [Gluon Ignite](http://gluonhq.com/labs/ignite/) can handle dependency injection needs if you have them.