# Design Patterns for alleviating / changing the visibility of an object

Tags: java, javafx, design-patterns

## Problem

I keep running across this paradigm where I have to write functions of the form `maybeUpdateEnabled`, where I change one variable that determines visibility and have to check against a load of others.

## Example

Imagine I have the following data (represented as strings here for convenience):

```
["apple", "pear", "tomato", "celery", "red pepper"]
```

and I provide the user with a GUI with two toggle-buttons, one for filtering out all things that are red, and one for filtering out all things that are vegetables. The user first filters out all of the reds, and then all of the vegetables, and only pears remain. When the user then toggles the red switch, the `red peppers`, which were initially filtered out, should still be invisible, as they are still being hidden via the vegetable filter.

## Question

Are there any Design Patterns which can help alleviate this? I was considering using bitmasks, or a stack of some kind, but I don't think I'll be able to logically avoid the `maybeUpdate` paradigm, which is a horrendous code smell to me.

### Edit

I would also like to add that this isn't necessarily a matter of "how do I do this", but rather "how do I make this not a pain in the neck". I can have any `n` numbers of fields, none of which have any particular guarantees of which conditions may be filtering out any `m` number of objects. I have a temporary fix in production for this, but I'd like to get in the practice of refactoring to provide a clean API, without having to refactor nearly everything.

### Edit 2

While I can't post the code, I can absolutely tell you that a bunch of `JFXToggleButtons` are being used, and Listeners are connecting to the `selectedProperty` "signal", which in my mind is creating a very tight coupling between the view, model and controller, as the view and controller are effectively the same underlying data structures and classes (which sucks alot). Changing the properties without the GUI has the benefit of automatically updating the controller, but unfortunately would emit changes for every single property change, an per the above edit, is horribly inefficient (and yes I have profiled it).

Comment: Java's in-built capabilities such as streams can easily handle your requirement.  You might want to add some relevant Java code to your question.

Comment: Bitmasks could work. We don't typically ask for generic suggestions at SO. If you try something and it doesn't work, post it and explain what went wrong

Comment: @Juan Mendes Unfortunately, due to the nature of the work, code samples are a no-go. This is as close as I can get.

Comment: @jfh I'm not talking about copy-pasting the code, I'm talking about creating a reduction of the problem stripped of anything that could be specific to your business

Comment: Since you're using JavaFX (according to the tags): If these items are stored in an `ObservableList` why not use a [`FilteredList`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html)?

Comment: Take a look at there related question: [Is there a way to implement a property like “rendered” on JAVAFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666982/is-there-a-way-to-implement-a-property-like-rendered-on-javafx) and the sample solution to it [Sample for creating a role based UI using JavaFX FXML](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/7229260).  Perhaps it will be useful in your case, perhaps not.

Comment: Your question is not about design patterns. A _Bitmask_ or or a _Stack_ are not design patterns. A stack is a data structure and a bitmask a binary operation.

Comment: @BionicCode While you are correct, my question is absolutely about design patterns, as the essence is not "which programming constructs should I use please write my code for me", but rather, "I have this architectural problem that is causing me maintenance woes, how can I alleviate that?" I am looking for higher level solutions. Also, In regards to posting my code, 1. It absolutely cannot be done, and 2. there is currently little to no actual design in the code itself. There are 1000s of lines connecting Event Listeners and it is in desperate need of refactoring.

Comment: Funny. I can swear your question reads like: I want to filter some items using toggle buttons. "Is there any Design Pattern which can help alleviate this? I was considering using bitmasks, or a stack of some kind...". To be honest this doesn't sound like your alledged: "I have this architectural problem that is causing me maintenance woes, how can I alleviate that?". You should make clear what you need and maybe rephrase your question.

Comment: I also wonder what secret code you have that you can't derive a simple representation on how you structured your code and how you are binding. And why "it absolutely cannot be done". It's absolutely not clear what you have so far and what you want, that's why you got no answers. You ask about filtering but you mean architecture. That's confusing. No offense, but you should rework your question.

Comment: I can see that, I'll probably have to rework my question regardless. As far as design patterns go, it's less about "how do I use a bitmask or stack", but rather (albeit implied) "what kind of design pattern should I use if I were to use a bitmask or stack", as I now have to implement interfaces and create some Builders, Controllers, etc. This becomes OBE if I use your suggestion, which is why I wouldn't necessarily consider either wrong, but I probably should've worded it such that it didn't sound like I was asking for constructs in place of patterns. P.S. think step above NDA.

Answer (score 1):

To filter a collection objects, the filter needs a criteria. This criteria must be an attribute of the object to filter. When filtering plain strings the criteria could be lexical, grammatical, syntactical or semantic.

You're obviously interested in the semantics of the strings. To make things easier you should use objects to represent the string data. The filter criteria could be a tag list in form of a `EnumSet<E>`.

First define a list of available tags. You can expose this list to the UI and also make it extensible via UI (extending the tag list still leaves your data objects close for modification):

```
public enum Tags
{
  RED, YELLOW, GREEN, VEGETABLE, FOOD, FRUIT, MEAT, SWEET, HOT, SPICEY
}
```

Then prepare the data object for filtering:

```
public interface IFilterable
{
  EnumSet<Tags> getTags();
  void setTags(EnumSet<Tags> tags);
}

public class DataObject implements IFilterable
{
  private EnumSet<Tags> tags; 
  public EnumSet<Tags> getTags() { 
    return this.tags; 
  }

  public void setTags(EnumSet<Tags> tags) { 
    this.tags = tags; 
  }
}
```

Filtering can be now easily achieved by using streams or the `javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList<E>` class.

To show only red vegetables (e.g. when the user modifies the fiter) use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ObservableList<DataObject> unfilteredObjects = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new DataObject(EnumSet.of(Tags.RED, Tags.VEGETABLE)), new DataObject(EnumSet.of(Tags.RED, Tags.FRUIT)));

  // A filtered collection that contains only red vegetables
  // In this case the size of redVegetables will be 1
  EnumSet<Tags> filterCriteria = EnumSet.of(Tags.RED, Tags.VEGTABLE);
  Predicate<DataObject> filterPredicate = dataObject -> dataObject.getTags().containsAll(filterCreiteria);
  FilteredList<DataObject> redVegetables = new FilteredList<>(unfilteredObjects, filterPredicate);
}
```

When you now bind your `ListView` to the `ObservableList` (or `FilteredList` since it implements `ObservableList`), only the filtered items will show and excluded items will automatically disappear from display.